# Hibernate AssertionFailure: null id in entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, spring-transactions

AM trying to perform some update operations in a catch block when an org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException is thrown as below

Am using Hibernate 4.3.6

```
try {
     services.entity.saveInstance(secQuestions)
}
catch(Exception e) {
     if(e instanceof org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException){
        userRegistrationRequest.requestProcessed = true
        infoMsg = userRegistrationRequest.infoMessage+' Exception: '+e.message
        userRegistrationRequest.infoMessage = infoMsg
        entityService.update(userRegistrationRequest)
        logger.info("Caught BaseApplicationException "+e.message)
        return;
 }
```

Here is my UserRegistrationRequest entity

```
@Audited
@javax.persistence.Entity
class UserRegistrationRequest implements IAmGroovy, Serializable, IVersionable {

@Autowired
protected transient Services         services;
protected answerOne;
protected answerTwo;
protected emailAddress;
protected firstName;
protected infoMessage;
protected lastName;
protected requestExpired;
protected requestProcessed;
SecurityQuestion securityQuestionOne;  
SecurityQuestion securityQuestionTwo; 
UserSecurityQuestions securityQuestions;
}
```

Here is my UserSecurityQuestions entity

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class UserSecurityQuestions implements IPersistentEntityInstance {

    private Long               id;
    private User               user;
    private SecurityQuestion   question1;
    private SecurityQuestion   question2;
    private String             answer1;
    private String             answer2;
    private String             hashString;
    private Timestamp          validThrough;
    private int                tries;
 }
```

Am getting the below error when try to perform update in catch block

```
    [Sep 17 11:48:14] ERROR | com.dc.core.common.controller.impl.BaseMultiActionController | null id in com.dc.apps.cp.security.model.UserSecurityQuestionsExt entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs) ERROR CODE(-1340973058)
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.dc.apps.cp.security.model.UserSecurityQuestionsExt entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:77)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:192)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:152)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:231)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:102)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:55)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
  at com.dc.core.security.container.SecureSessionProxy.flush(SecureSessionProxy.java:306)
  at com.dc.core.operations.service.impl.OperationService.performSingleOperation(OperationService.java:778)
  at com.dc.core.presentation.presenter.impl.ScreenPresenter.performSingleOperation(ScreenPresenter.java:1187)
  at com.dc.core.presentation.controller.springmvc.impl.ItemScreenRenderController.performOperation(ItemScreenRenderController.java:952)
  at com.dc.core.presentation.controller.springmvc.impl.ItemScreenRenderController.performItemScreenOperation(ItemScreenRenderController.java:229)
  at com.dc.core.presentation.controller.springmvc.impl.ItemScreenRenderController.performOperation(ItemScreenRenderController.java:433)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1397.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
  at com.dc.core.common.controller.impl.CustomMultiActionController.invokeNamedMethod(CustomMultiActionController.java:504)
  at com.dc.core.common.controller.impl.CustomMultiActionController.handleRequestInternal(CustomMultiActionController.java:430)
  at com.dc.core.common.controller.impl.BaseMultiActionController.handleRequestInternal(BaseMultiActionController.java:623)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:154)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

If I catch Exception instead of ConstraintViolationException am seeing the below error

```
  Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
    at com.dc.core.security.container.SecureSessionProxy.save(SecureSessionProxy.java:685)
    at com.dc.core.common.dao.impl.GenericWriteDAO.create(GenericWriteDAO.java:37)
    at com.dc.core.entity.dao.impl.EntityInstanceDAO.create(EntityInstanceDAO.java:63)
    at com.dc.core.entity.service.impl.EntityService.create(EntityService.java:278)
    at com.dc.core.api.EntityAPI.saveInstance(EntityAPI.java:188)

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__P_USER_S__B9BE370E29ACF837'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.P_USER_SECURITY_QUESTIONS'. The duplicate key value is (9).
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 162 more
```

Can someone help me, is there a better way to perform update operation in catch block?

Comment: Your `userRegistrationRequest` is a new object or a existing object which is present in hibernate session (meaning, does it have a valid id that hibernate understands)?

Comment: Yes userRegistrationRequest is valid and an existing object. The above is part of a command which pulls the requests form user_registration_request table(tied to UserRegistrationRequest entity) and does some manipulation on the userRegistrationRequest object

Comment: Are you sure the problem lies in the code you listed above? What line, do you think?

Comment: I updated the question with stacktrace when i catch Exception instead of ConstraintViolationException. The problem is when i Catch ConstraintViolationException its not even going to my update code and throwing the org.hibernate.AssertionFailure exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:
Keep both the updates in different Transactions. If there is an exception in try, rollback the first Transaction in catch, clear the session and start a new Transaction to update in catch.

```
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction(); 
        services.entity.saveInstance(secQuestions);
        tx.commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        session.clear();
        if(e instanceof org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException){
            Transaction tx1 = session.beginTransaction();
            userRegistrationRequest.requestProcessed = true
            infoMsg = userRegistrationRequest.infoMessage+' Exception: '+e.message
            userRegistrationRequest.infoMessage = infoMsg
            entityService.update(userRegistrationRequest);
            tx1.commit();
            logger.info("Caught BaseApplicationException "+e.message)
            return;
     }
}
```

Comment: Am getting org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported with your solution

Comment: Are you sure that the first transaction is either successfully committed or rollbacked  before beginning the second one as you can't have two simultaneous active transactions in one session.